# Help identifying a Murray bicycle

Tags: identify-this-bike

I know it is a Murray its serial number is M06 140 60056. It is chrome, had a 3 speed rear hub and triangular sears branded reflectors. I unfortunately didn’t take a pic before tearing it down.

[image]

And yes I turned the handlebars upside down. I’m intending on converting it into a motorized bike (I am keeping all the original parts just in case, though the rear will needs a few spokes).

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles.se Robert. Do you need to know anymore than you already do? This is a great place for Q and A but unfortunately identify this bike question are normally closed or duped as little value comes from knowing the full details. You already know it's a Murray which is more than most know.

Comment: At a guess, its a 70s or 80s bike.  Which is good because there were far fewer standards back then.

Comment: It says Nassau on the chain guard (really light like it’s been rubbed off) other than that it appears to be a Monterey thanks for the help

Answer (score 5):

According to a thread called "[Murray serial number project](https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/murray-serial-number-project.7014/)" on thecabe.com serial number "MO6 140 60056" indicates 1966.

> In 65 they were changing there serial number style and by then they were on the left rear dropout. Some 65 bikes had an MO5 which stood for Murray of Ohio 1965. After these 3 digits was a 2 or 3 digit model number followed by and X and a 1 or 2 digit number that I will discuss momentarily.
>   MO5 = 65
>   MO6 = 66
>   MO7 = 67
>   MO8 = 68
>   In 69, they changed the layout yet again. They dropped the O. They also went to a 4 digit model number.
>   M9 = 69
>   M0 = 70
>   and so on.

So, in your case the format should be
MO6 = 1966
140 = model number
60056 = ?

Finding a 1966 Murray catalog to verify that such a bike was made took me to "[1966 Murray Specials Catalog](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/musclebikeforums/1966-murray-specials-catalog-t162.html)" at tapatalk.com
[image]
Sadly, the page is cut off so that the model name is not visible. Even cut off the bike's name looks like "MONA ---" rather than "MONT ---"
What we can see of the description indicates that there was a three speed made in 1966 but the men's model was metallic green - not chrome.
Squinting at the head badge in the picture just right might convince you that the head badge is a match.

There is something that might be a model number in the picture "6-130X66 BOYS 26". If that's the model number it might be that the "140" on your bike refers to a chrome three speed Monterey and the "130" refers to a painted some other name.
Lots of speculation there.
Murray made different bikes for different retail outlets at the same time. The same bike might have had different model names or finishes.

On a side note,
These bikes did not have a good reputation for standing up under rough usage.
Motorization will put stress on this frame that it was never designed to handle. It would be wise to select a different frame to motorize.